# in what order the process in mpi executes ... i mean rank wise order? ex: rank==0 first and rank==1 next?

Tags: c, mpi

In what order the process in `MPI` executes?. I mean rank wise order?

e.g: `rank == 0` first and `rank == 1` next?.

I considered two process by mentioning at runtime by giving the below command:

`mpirun -np 2 example`.

What is the order that will be followed by `MPI` in C to execute the program.

Comment: If the question is about MPI using C, why tag it java and C#?

Answer (score 3):

There is no guarantee as far as I know. After all, with MPI, you expect to run processes on various processors. It doesn't make sense to force an ordering on them.

That said, you shouldn't rely on the ordering either. In other words, you don't need to and shouldn't care what the order of execution is, if there even were any.

Answer (score 3):

Processes in an MPI job execute **concurrently** given that they don't time-share execution units (cores/CPUs). Execution of various parts of the code can then be synchronised using either barriers (`MPI_BARRIER`) or a pair of synchronous blocking operations (`MPI_SSEND` in the sender /`MPI_RECV` in the receiver).

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of executing your program with MPI is that the processes are executed in parallel so the ordering is not fixed in time and depends on your program and the environment.